# Any software opening a png image in a way that trasparent parts show behind windows?

Tags: transparency, image-viewers

I need a software that could open a png file which has some transparent parts (alpha channel) in a way that transparent parts are really transparent in the software window (not checkered parts as it is in usual softwares).

I mean that software window works as image layer that is above other softwares windows so transparent parts of PNG image show behind windows.

Is there any such software in ubuntu?

Comment: Well if you have some programming experience I found this: https://gist.github.com/mertyildiran/7708a3764ebd16ee2a5d4f3801207bfd